# Install CDT of Eclipse 4.15 broken?

Tags: eclipse-cdt

Started with Java Eclipse on Windows.  Went to Help > Install New software.

There are a bunch of download sites.  No idea what is what, so I chose the first one,

2020-06 - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-06

CDT said it installed OK.  Is visible in Help > About Eclipse > Installation Version 9.11.1.

However, there is no other evidence that it is there.  No option on File > New > Project, Window > Perspective, does not recognize .c files.

Running with JDK 1.8.

I suppose I could just install a completely new Eclipse with the CDT bundle, but then will it conflict with my existing one?

BTW.  How does Eclipse itself find the Java_version (not for Java projects, for the editor which is written in Java)?  Does it respect JAVA_HOME environment variable?  Or does it use the awful registry settings?

Answer (score 0):

My hack solution was to just download a second instance of eclipse, with the cdt stuff pre-configured.  So two completely independent installations of eclipse, one for Java work one for C work.

Never succeeded in getting them to work together.